# Get Local IP-Configuration including DHCP Value nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to get my local IP-Configuration using Nodejs OS.

```
var os = require('os');

var networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();

console.log(networkInterfaces);
```

This works so far but i want to get the DHCP Value aswell but it only shows following:

```
{
  'LAN-Verbindung': [
    {
      address: 'fe80::f579:a325:8dde:2280',
      netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
      family: 'IPv6',
      mac: '00:ff:9c:76:56:26',
      internal: false,
      cidr: 'fe80::f579:a325:8dde:2280/64',
      scopeid: 46
    },
    {
      address: '10.32.208.222',
      netmask: '255.255.255.252',
      family: 'IPv4',
      mac: '00:ff:9c:76:56:26',
      internal: false,
      cidr: '10.32.208.222/30'
    }
  ]}
```

For me it is really important to get if DHCP is true or false. But how can i get this Value.

Thanks for your help guys